# Device not found when I'm executing openCL program

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

My machine has AMD and NVIDIA devices with RHEL OS. I have implemented a program in OpenCL with two different contexts for both the platforms (NVIDIA and AMD). Whenever I'm executing the program it is showing as DEVICE_NOT_FOUND. If I'm running the same program with sudo permission it is executing on both devices. What could be the problem with normal user? How to solve this problem.?

Comment: Are you sitting in front of the machine and logged into X or are you logged in remotely?

Comment: @Matthias: Remotely logged in

Comment: Look at this question, my answer worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061296/how-do-i-test-opencl-on-gpu-when-logged-in-remotely-on-mac/14594492#14594492